# How to start MongoDB server?

Tags: mongodb, mongohq

I am having a PHP webservice that is connected with MongoDB server hosted on MongoHQ suddenly i got this exception:

```
exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Operation now in progress' in /****/classes/mongo.db.class.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /****/classes/mongo.db.class.php(8): Mongo->__construct('***********') #1 /filepath/filename.php(14): include_once('******') #2 {main}Problem during mongodb initialization. Please start mongodb server.
```

What is this exception about? 
I dont know what shall i do with it? 
how to start MongoDB Server?

Comment: Have you tried conncting to the database using the Mongo shell? Does that work? Just to make sure it is not related to PHP-driver...

Comment: Actually NO,  all the work was done by a developer and he couldn't continue with me because he travelled to another country .. kindly tell me how to connect using mongo shell?? i have no ida about it

Comment: MongoHQ can provide you with connections details, and here you can find information about how to use the shell: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/mongo/

Answer (score 0):

Dos
mongod --dbpath "C://mongodata"